# Correct way to customize color of rhandsontable inside a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

So, I'm creating a shiny app and I'd like to color some rows in a table generated with rhandsontable.

I'm following this very good tutorial: https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/

Specifically, I'm interested in this part:

```
library(rhandsontable)
DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

col_highlight = 2
row_highlight = c(5, 7)

rhandsontable(DF, col_highlight = col_highlight, 
              row_highlight = row_highlight,
              width = 550, height = 300) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = "
    function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
      Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);

      tbl = this.HTMLWidgets.widgets[0]

      hcols = tbl.params.col_highlight
      hcols = hcols instanceof Array ? hcols : [hcols] 
      hrows = tbl.params.row_highlight
      hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows] 

      if (hcols.includes(col) && hrows.includes(row)) {
        td.style.background = 'red';
      }
      else if (hcols.includes(col)) {
        td.style.background = 'lightgreen';
      }
      else if (hrows.includes(row)) {
        td.style.background = 'pink';
      }

      return td;
  }")
```

This code works in RStudio, but not on Shiny (the table simply doesn't show up). There is an explanation in the website, saying that if using this on Shiny, we should add that part to the code:

```
HTMLWidgets.widgets.filter(function(widget) {
  // this should match the table id specified in the shiny app
  return widget.name === "hot"
})[0];
```

However, since I know nothing about javascript, I'm a little lost as to where should this part go. I tried many things, including:

```
 rhandsontable(DF, col_highlight = col_highlight, 
                  row_highlight = row_highlight,
                  width = 550, height = 300) %>%
      hot_cols(renderer = "
        function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
          Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
          HTMLWidgets.widgets.filter(function(widget) {
            // this should match the table id specified in the shiny app
            return widget.name === \"hot\"
          })[0];
      ..
```

But it's still not correct.

This is probably a very basic question for anyone familiar with js, but what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: can you include the code you used in Shiny (ui.R and server.R)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple example of colouring columns and rows.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    rHandsontableOutput("hot")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
        DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, big = LETTERS[1:10])
        col_highlight = c(0, 1)
        row_highlight = c(3)
    
        rhandsontable(DF, col_highlight = col_highlight, row_highlight = row_highlight) %>%
        hot_cols(renderer = "
            function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                if (instance.params) {
                    hcols = instance.params.col_highlight
                    hcols = hcols instanceof Array ? hcols : [hcols]
                    hrows = instance.params.row_highlight
                    hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows]
                }
                if (instance.params && hcols.includes(col)) td.style.background = 'red';
                if (instance.params && hrows.includes(row)) td.style.background = 'yellow';
            }")
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, that works. I just don't get why booleans, that usually appear as checkbox in rhandsontables, become strings once we do this step. This also happens outside shiny, as in the site example. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Booleans becomes strings because of this line `Handsontable.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);` numeric render tries to render it as a number ... There is also `Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);` but it also mess up booleans. You can see it here https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#column_types last example

Comment: this doesnt seem to work anymore with version 0.3.6.1. It gives this error: `TypeError: Handsontable.NumericRenderer is undefined`

Comment: It does not work for me at all. Neither in RStudio, nor inside a Shiny App.

Comment: Change `Handsontable.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);` to `Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the discussion of dealing Booleans in accepted answer. Note that `hot_col` can assign which columns be formatted. Hence just exclude the boolean column. For instance, the below code only used column 1 and column 2 and column 3, bool, was removed.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    rHandsontableOutput("hot")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
        DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, big = LETTERS[1:10],bool=T)
        col_highlight = c(0, 1)
        row_highlight = c(3)
    
        rhandsontable(DF, col_highlight = col_highlight, row_highlight = row_highlight) %>%
        hot_col(col=c(1,2),renderer = "
            function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                if (instance.params) {
                    hcols = instance.params.col_highlight
                    hcols = hcols instanceof Array ? hcols : [hcols]
                    hrows = instance.params.row_highlight
                    hrows = hrows instanceof Array ? hrows : [hrows]
                }
                if (instance.params && hcols.includes(col)) td.style.background = 'red';
                if (instance.params && hrows.includes(row)) td.style.background = 'yellow';
            }")
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The results are as:

[image: Results for dealing with bool]